# Which JavaScript file holds .ts URLs

Tags: video, javascript, embedded

Some videos embedded in webpages segment the video into media files with a `.ts` extension. These files are loaded on-demand to reduce lag. You can see this then "inspecting" a webpage and looking at the traffic/things that load.

Is it customary for a website to load an asset that holds the relative (or absolute) path for the `.ts` video files? If so, what is the naming convention for this file? I feel as if I've seen this before.